# Negating values in asymptote

Tags: asymptote

How do I negate values in Asymptote? I tried using `not(true)` but there does not seem to be an inbuilt `not` function for this.

Sure, I can define a function to do this, but I just want to know if there is standard way to do this in Asymptote

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're looking for the `!` negation operator.

```
bool b = true; // b now equals true
b = !b;        // b now equal false
```

This operator and others can be found in section 6.9 of the [documentation](http://asymptote.sourceforge.net/).